# What is a word for someone who tends not to think too much about life?

Tags: word-choice

What is a word for someone who tends not to think too deeply; often about life, themselves or the world (something more neutral than "shallow" or "oblivious")? 
Perhaps my difficulty is that i personally don't think that not thinking is a neutral characteristic.  Plus, the type of person i am trying to describe does not necessarily take life with ease or serenity.  The word i seek is more about thought-life, than temperament. A non-thinking person can still have a negative, angry, unpleasant (etc.)  outlook on life, they just don't question it.

Comment: Please see: http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info

Answer (score 19):

I'd say such a person is ***[happy-go-lucky](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/happy-go-lucky)***

> A *happy-go-lucky* ​person does not ​plan much and ​accepts what ​happens without ​becoming ​worried.

[Cambridge Online]

It implies that they are carefree and accept life the way it is.

Comment: _carefree_ is a good option itself.

Answer (score 17):

**Carefree** is a viable option that I use myself.

```
[a :  having no worries or troubles]
```

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carefree

Usage:
She has a carefree attitude toward life.

Comment: Freebird can also be used.

Answer (score 10):

***Unreflecting*** is defined as "not engaging in reflection or thought" ([here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unreflecting)). ***Unreflective*** is a variant that works nicely for what you want.

Answer (score 8):

***Easygoing*** comes to mind. I think it captures a facet of the meaning you specified.

> able to ​stay ​calm about things that ​anger or ​worry most ​people

[American English, [Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/easygoing)]

> relaxed and not ​easily ​upset or ​worried

[British English, [Cambridge Advanced Learners Dictionary & Thesaurus](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/easy-going)]

One might expect that a person who does not tend to think too much about life, the universe, and everything would, in turn, tend to be less opinionated, less stressed, and less confrontational than the average bear, i.e. ***easygoing***.

Answer (score 5):

Blithe

[Definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blithe)

```
- of a happy lighthearted character or disposition
- lacking due thought or consideration"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a somewhat neutral or even positive term for the type of person you describe: pragmatic.

> **Pragmatic**
>   2 :  relating to matters of fact or practical affairs often to the exclusion of intellectual or artistic matters :  practical as opposed to idealistic [- M-w](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pragmatic)

Answer (score 1):

How about "aloof"?

> removed or distant either physically or emotionally  [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aloof)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider [**light-hearted**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lighthearted). This is often associated with people who are cheerful or carefree.

Also **lighthearted:**

Free from care, anxiety, or seriousness. Or cheerfully optimistic and hopeful. [**MW**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lighthearted)

Not being burdened by trouble, worry, or care; happy and carefree. [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lighthearted)

Answer (score 1):

"Slacker", but that probably kind of negative .

"fancy-free" as in footloose and fancy-free. But I think that just means for temporary time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd describe them as a **simple** person

Answer (score 0):

Philistine: "A hollow gut, full of fear and hope that God will have mercy!"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philistinism

Comment: If you are not sure about the answer or you need further clarification from an author you can leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @haha: Except that Burton can't do that because of insufficient reputation at this site. _Philistine_ may be a defensible suggestion as a term meaning "having a crude, shallow, and materialistic view of life"—but how it relates to the quotation that Burton includes with it is far from obvious.

Comment: OK, sorry I didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: The quote is meant as a definition

Comment: Goethe said it so I thought --- Why not?

Answer (score 0):

phlegmatic - self-possessed, calm, or composed.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phlegmatic

Comment: It's a great word, though I'm not sure it conveys obliviousness so much as self-possession, with perhaps an element of inertial immovability.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'indifferent' or 'apathetic'

Comment: Can you explain why these would be good choices? One easy way to do that is to cite a dictionary definition. "Apathetic" doesn't seem very neutral to me.

Comment: It's not that I'm apathetic, its just that I don't care. -Office Space (I think)